# WooCommerce - Product with variation that includes both a physical and digital product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a client who wishes to sell a book like so:
e-book: $5
Physical book: $20
ebook and Physical book: $22

Now I know that I can add variations that are either a physical or digital product.  But what about a variation that has both?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Variation product for 3 types of books with different price. You can also chose which one is Downloadable product . (  [Check the screenshot](https://prnt.sc/E0oVxvdzj5-B) )